# iframe Internal Server Error 500 - only in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

i have a website with an iframe and it works fine with FF & Chrome but in IE i got:
HTTP Status 500 (Tomcat). I don't have access to the log-files.

Why does it happen?

edit:

here is the Website: http://archiv.difmoe.eu/kalender/ubrtest.php

i used fiddler2 to get this report:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/5.0.26 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.apache.jasper.JasperException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:372)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
com.exlibris.digitool.common.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:50)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.mets.toc_jsp._jspService(toc_jsp.java:74)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    com.exlibris.digitool.common.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:50)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.0.26 logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/5.0.26

Answer (score 0):

It's because the **cookie with the session ID** was not being passed.
You will need to **send the header on every page** that sets a **cookie**.

**PHP:**

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

**ASP.NET:**

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

**Django:**

```
response = render_to_response('mytemplate.html')
response["P3P"] = 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'
```

**JSP:**

```
response.addHeader("P3P","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"")
```

Reference:
http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies

Answer (score 0):

Old question but it has a lot of Google juice so maybe this will help someone in the future:

I had this same issue with an ASP.NET MVC website. I had to remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from the `POST` method in my Controller as well as removing it from the view. Then everything worked fine (in all versions of IE). My guess is it is still related to headers in some form or fashion.